# Price modification works on cart but not on the order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm writing a function to modify prices.
Depending on the total price of products from within some categories, a rebate is applied (-1 to -4%)
The function works fine with the cart and mini cart, up to the "order" page. But the rebate is not applied on the actual order !

```
// hook :
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', array($this,'action_woocommerce_before_calculate_totals'), 10 ); 

// function
function action_woocommerce_before_calculate_totals( $WC_Cart ) {
// 1. verifications... if eligible then proceed to :

// 2. sum up eligible products amounts
$eligible_items = array();
$total_eligible_price = 0;
foreach ( $WC_Cart->get_cart_contents() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
   if(!isProductEligible($cart_item)) continue;
   $eligible_items[$cart_item_key] = array(
      'full_price' => $cart_item['data']->get_price(),
   );
$total_eligible_price += $cart_item['data']->get_price() *     $cart_item['quantity'];
}

// 3. find the correct ratio
$price_ratio_to_apply = getPriceRatioForTotal($total_eligible_price);

// 4. and calculate the discounted price for eligible items
foreach($eligible_items as $item_key => $item) {
   $eligible_items[$item_key]['discounted_price'] = $item['full_price'] * $price_ratio_to_apply;
}

// 5 then apply discounted prices to cart items
foreach($WC_Cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) { 
   if(!isset($eligible_items[$cart_item_key])) continue;
   $discounted_price = $eligible_items[$cart_item_key]['discounted_price'];
   $cart_item['data']->set_price( $discounted_price );
}
```

The function works perfect on the cart page and the order page (other functions are used to display full/discounted price on cart item lines)
But doesn't do anything to the order when the order is actually validated by the customer.

Is there another hook I should add to apply the discounted price when order is validated ?

Comment: Your code is incomplete as for example `isProductEligible()` and `getPriceRatioForTotal()` are not defined… Now all **checkings and calculations should be done before** like in [**this answer code**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50729010/3730754) … Remember that *"Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."***

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to hook to one of these actions:

```
 do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order );
```

or

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', $order, $data );
```

This will update the price just before it's being created and saved.

But I must say I think it would be better to apply a coupon dynamically. This way you will see the discount on the order, it will be much convenient for you and for your clients.